# Comparing Strings in Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I am having a lot of trouble comparing a string in a variable to an actual string in batch. Here's the script:

```
 set failure=0
 for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`"wmic PRINTER where name='10.146.2.52 - HP Color LaserJet CP5225n' GET Name 2>&1"`) do (
 ::Quotes around variable seem to have no effect. Same result w/ or w/o them.
 if /I "%%L"=="No Instance(s) Available." set failure=1
 echo %failure%   %%L
 )
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Why does the if statement fail? The values clearly match. Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different gotchas here.

1) Wmic appends sometimes an extra `CR` character at the end of a line, which would be part of the string.
2) You can't access `failure` with a percent expansion inside of a block.
3) The missing quotes around `%%L`

Try this

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set failure=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`"wmic PRINTER where name='10.146.2.52 - HP Color LaserJet CP5225n' GET Name 2>&1"`) do (
    set "line=%%L"
    set "head=!line:~0,9!"
    if "!head!"=="No Instan" set failure=1
    echo 123-%%L-456
)
echo %failure%
```

Comment: The condition is still false. Failure is not set to 1 but it should be bc `%%L` does equal "No Instances Available". Is there a way to handle that `CR` character?

Comment: I see the problem, it seems the missing quotes, I edit my code

Comment: What is the output of echo 123-%%L-456? It could be 123-No Instance(s) Available.-456` or 456-No Instance(s) Available.

Answer (score 1):

The string often has more text before/after it - even if there is a cr there to deal with - and Wmic is an odd beast to handle.

You could do a separate test and pipe the result through `find` or `findstr` to set an errorlevel.  Something like the following - or use the errorlevel that `find` sets to 0 when the text is found.

```
wmic PRINTER where name='10.146.2.52 - HP Color LaserJet CP5225n' GET Name 2>&1 |find "No Instance" >nul && echo printer not detected
```

Enclose the %%L in quotes when you echo it to see if obvious trailing text is there.

This is what I get in debug, with the extra CR/0D and plus it gives you some nulls for good measure. :)

```
0B48:0100  4E 6F 20 49 6E 73 74 61-6E 63 65 28 73 29 20 41   No Instance(s) A
0B48:0110  76 61 69 6C 61 62 6C 65-2E 0D 0D 0A 0D 00 0A 00   vailable........
```

Comment: @jeb Me too, see my post above for the debug output - Windows 8 Pro 32 bit English.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the findstr? How do I findstr on a var?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the parentheses in the string `No Instance(s) Available.`.

The easiest resolution is to probably just substring out the first part of the string, thereby ignoring the parentheses.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

 SET failure=0
 FOR  /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in (`"wmic PRINTER where name='10.146.2.52 - HP Color LaserJet CP5225n' GET Name 2>&1"`) DO (
   SET str=%%L
   SET substr=!str:~0,11!
   IF /I "!substr!"=="No Instance" SET failure=1
   ECHO !failure!   !substr!
 )
```